# OleDbConnection Error in Conn.Open()

Tags: c#

I am trying to read data from an excel file. The path of the file is set in config file. I have created a library class for connection purpose and another library class for storing the value retrieved in c# object. I am running it entirely on a console application. But I end up getting an invalid argument exception in Conn.Open().

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Invalid argument

This is my Connection class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExcelLib
{
  public class ExcelLib
  {
    public DataSet Excel()
    {
      string filepath = 
        Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Path"]);
      string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath 
        + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;ReadOnly=True;HDR=Yes;\"";
      string query = "Select * from [jobs_productioncontrol$]";
      using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
      {
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        OleDbDataAdapter command = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        command.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        command.Fill(ds);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.Tables.Add();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
          ExcelData data = new ExcelData();
          data.JobNo = row["JobNo"].ToString();
          data.EventNo = row["EventNo"].ToString();
        }
        return ds;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exception you are getting? What is the message of exception?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
 
Additional information: Invalid argument.

Comment: can you run your project in debug mode and look at the value of 'filepath'?

Comment: Its showing Filepath is null

Comment: So now you need to make sure that file path has valid value.

Comment: So, it's because of filepath variable, may be your app.config has no keyvalue 'Path'

Comment: The class which i have shown above is a class library. and i am running it through a console application by creating an object of the type ExcelLib.i.e, name of the class library

Comment: @kulbans1991 So in the `App.config` file of the consuming executable, you need to make sure there is a `Path` value.

Comment: <add key="Path" value="C:\Users\ADMKSingh\Documents\jobs_productioncontrol.xlsx"/>..That is wat i have in app.config

Comment: @kulbans1991 Personally, I would recommend passing the filepath into the function allowing the consumer to control how it is loaded.

Comment: @ryachza I would have done that, but my requirenment itself is to pass the url of the excel file through configuration

Comment: @kulbans1991 So your `App.config` looks something like `<configuration><appSettings><add key="Path" value="C:\Users\ADMKSingh\Documents\jobs_productioncontrol.x‌​lsx"/></appSettings></configuration>`? The `App.config` file needs to be in the directory of the executable - you have it associated with the consuming application, not the class library, correct? At this point, if you've verified that `filepath` is `null`, there is an issue with your `appSettings` - you'll need to debug that.

Comment: @kulbans1991 Certainly, having the path stored in a configuration file is fine/good. However, embedding magical run time locations inside of a class library [I believe] will only cause problems. The consumer should load it from the configuration file and propagate it to the class library, which has the benefit of documenting the dependency in the function signature.

Comment: @ryacha thank youuuuu soooo much.. I was stupid to provide the configuration in class library rather than providing it in the console application..Hats off to you..Worked well..Thanks again

Comment: @kulbans1991 Sure thing. I don't specifically recall, but I'm sure I learned this lesson the hard way many years ago. I posted an answer to formalize the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments on the question, `filepath` is `null` indicating the `appSettings` were are configured as expected. The `App.config` file needs to be associated with the consuming application, not the class library.

I would strongly recommend the consuming application be responsible for loading of configurable settings and have them propagated into the class library. It would have likely prevented this issue, and would likely prevent other sources of confusion in the future.